# Lowercasing complex object field names in azure data factory data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to lowercase the field names in a row entry in azure data flow. Inside a complex object I've got something like

```
{
 "field": "sample",
 "functions": [
    {
      "Name": "asdf",
      "Value": "sdfsd"
    },
    {
      "Name": "dfs",
      "Value": "zxcv"
    }
  ]
}
```

and basically what I want is for "Name" and "Value to be "name" and "value". However can't seem to use any expressions that will work for the nested fields of a complex object in the expression builder.

I've tried using a something like a select with a rule-based mapping that is the rule being 1 == 1 and lower($$), but with $$ it seems to only work for root columns of the complex object and not the nested fields inside.

Comment: Can you try selecting "functions" as the hierarchy level in the rule-based mapping in your Select transformation?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by **@Mark Kromer MSFT**, for changing case of columns inside complex type select the **functions** in the Hierarchy level.

Please check the below for your reference:

[image]

Here, I have used both.
You can see the difference in results.

[image]